# How to pass neo4j cypher result.records as JSON across the network?

Tags: neo4j, microservices, nestjs

I have a nestjs api REST gateway that speaks to a nestjs microservice dbserver. The dbserver query a neo4j 4.1.1 database for all queries made by the gateway. The architecture I am using is one dbserver that will accept/respond to all other services requiring db services....(to scale I would launch another dbserver).

My problem is the dbserver is unaware of the cypher query contents because the cypher query is built in the gateway and passed to the dbserver as a data string. Therefore I cannot use statements like:

const user = result.records[0].get('user').properties;

since the key 'user' isn't known to the dbserver.  The dbserver query look like this:

```
.......
const session = await this.getWriteSession(databaseOrTransaction as string);
const result = await session.run(cypher, params);
session.close();
return result;
```

So I want to return the complete result.records  array as JSON object to the gateway.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this answer will cover all use cases but I found that using the .map method on the result.records provide an answer in at least two use case...the following will convert result.records to an array of objects or an array of values:

```
const data = result.records.map(obj => obj.get(0).properties ? obj.get(0).properties : obj.get(0));
```

This would cover

```
 MATCH(v:Person) RETURN v AS vehicles;
```

and

```
 MATCH(v:Person) RETURN v.name AS names
```

I would appreciate any improvement.